# How to calculate the "curviness" of a curve with a set of points?

Tags: java, math

I have an array of points (from the user swiping on the screen). I want to calculate how "curvy" the array of points are. For example, a curve closely resembling a straight line would be less curvy than a half circle.

I've considered fitting a curve to the points and calculating the radius of curvature, but I don't think it would work because the points don't necessarily form a function every time (fails vertical line test)?

I'd prefer the solution to be simpler/higher performance instead of high accuracy. I don't need the entire solution spelled out for me, just a nudge in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: If you're looking for a mathematical function to calculate "curviness" then your better off asking this question on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @jonny-henly this context is more fitting because i was looking for a simple solution that is performance friendly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty cheap complexity solution, but it's going to be less accurate if your points sweep out more than a single curve, i.e. if it goes from concave up to concave down or something.  But, if the concavity of your points stays the same over the dataset, this should be good.

For each group of three points (ordered from left to right), call them A, B, C, consider the following.  Calculate the degree given by angle ABC.  Then, average that value over each group of three points.  If the points are in a straight line, the average will be 180.  If the points are more curved, the average will be much less.

Comment: this works perfectly. thank you